# JavaScript data validator?

Tags: javascript, json, validation

Looking for a library that could validate input like, for example:

`{ points: array of { x: positive and < 20, y: positive and < 15 } }`

Preferably working on both server and client side and returning a boolean or throwing an exception.

What I explicitly don't need is string or form validation, I just want to check if JSON sent by client is safe for processing without a ton of dispersed checks as I go.

Comment: json is always safe.look for jsonschema onnpm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, wrote it myself.

- https://bitbucket.org/virtulis/validata/overview
- https://www.npmjs.org/package/validata

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [**Skematic**](https://github.com/mekanika/skematic).

> Data structure and rule validation engine. Robust schema for JS objects.

It lets you design data models, then format and validate data against those models. Works in browser (`Skematic` global) or Node/io.js.

To solve your request, something basic like this should work:

```
// -- Define a simple data structure
var YourData = {
  points: {
    type:'array', 
    default: [],
    schema: {
      x: { type: 'number', required: true, rules: { min:0, max:20 } },
      y: { type: 'number', required: true, rules: { min:0, max:15 } }
    }
  }
};

// -- Validate an object
Skematic.validate( YourData, {points:[ {x:-1,y:10} ]} );
// {valid:false, 
//  errors:{
//    points: {0:{x:['Failed: min']}}
// }}
```